# What if anything is the security differences between team viewer 7 and team viewer 9?

Tags: rdp, teamviewer

Is anyone aware of any major overhauls or security fixes to Team Viewer 9 (since v7) or does the popular accuvant blog (http://blog.accuvant.com/bthomasaccuvant/teamviewer-authentication-protocol-part-1-of-3/) still hold true?  (This blog was written for v7).

It seems from other SE posts and that the general consensus is that team viewer isn't secure, but is team viewer 9 any more secure than team viewer 7?  If so, how?  The only basic change I noticed is that the passcode is no longer a 4 digit code but is now 6 digits and alpha numeric (not sure if it was also alpha numeric or not before).

On their website I also noticed that there is now two factor authentication, if I were to use team viewer 9 with two factor, would I still have a security risk?

Comment: Increased passcode complexity addresses one of the issues. The plaintext communication between server-client is the other and I see no mention. It would need to be verified.

Comment: Would this plain text communication be any less secure than using lets say VNC with a relay server?  That is the other option I am looking at, but find that to be less desirable because I don't have access to a dedicated machine that is exposed to the internet.